# Как сделать цифровую подпись на android apk файл?

Tags: android-studio, google-play, apk, ionic

Google Play принимает только подписанные ключом приложения.
У меня уже больше недели проблема в том, что apk файл я создал, но подписать сертификатом я не могу.
Подскажите, как сгенерировать проект с ключом, что б его принял Google Play?
Проект изначально на Ionic, но как я понял, и во Flutter и в React Native подобная история. Я ни один из фреймворков не могу опубликовать на Google Play.

Я пробовал  как здесь https://ionicframework.com/docs/deployment/play-store
`keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk alias_name
```

Но получаю ошибки.
Кстити Android Studio тоже не билдит проект с ключом.
Я уже не знаю, в чём может быть дело?

Comment: Чтобы избавиться от ошибки, ее нужно озвучить

Comment: Разобрался C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\31.0.0-rc5\zipalign.exe -v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk signed.apk